# IE8 e.preventDefault() only works once (ignored after ajax submission)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, jquery-events

I'm submitting a form using AJAX with help from the [jquery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/). It works great EXCEPT that the `e.preventDefault()` only works once in IE8. After the second submission the page redirects to the url of the form.

I'm pretty sure I need to do some kind of event delegation, but I'm not entirely sure how to do it.

The context is a wordpress site. The following script appears right before the registration form HTML.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return (s)
      ? this.before(s).remove()
      : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $("form input").removeAttr('tabindex');

        ajaxregister = function(e) {
            //e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).animate({opacity:0}, 500);
            $(this).siblings("#loading").fadeIn();
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                //cache : false,
                //url:'http://streetofwalls.dev/wp-login.php?action=register'
                success: function( data ) {
                    //console.log(data);

                    var $message = $(data).find('.message').outerHTML();
                    var $error = $(data).find('#login_error').outerHTML();
                    var $form = $(data).find('#registerform').outerHTML();
                    //console.log( 'success' );

                    //$(e.target).html( ( ($error) ? $error : $message ) + $form ).fadeTo(500,1);
                    var target_id = $(e.target).attr("id");
                    $("#"+target_id).html( ( ($error) ? $error : $message ) + $form ).animate({opacity:1}, 500);
                    $("#"+target_id).siblings("#loading").css('display', 'none');

                }
            });
        return false;
        }

        $(".widget_reg_widg #registerform").submit( ajaxregister ); //should this be .delegate() ???


    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Might be helpful to include: Is this just straight-up HTML? Is it a framework like ASP.NET Web Forms that screws with your form events?
Also, I haven't tried, but could you get this repro in jsfiddle?

Comment: I updated the question. It's straight-up HTML.

Comment: I see you are using jquery's delegate() function, but using the jquery form plugin. Skimming over the examples, it looks like the form plugin uses "$(selector).ajaxForm(argsObject)" to bind events. Perhaps you should use the form methods rather than raw jquery API.. Have you tried this?

Comment: @aikeru I should clarify that I'm currently using .submit() for the production version. The variation with .delegate() was my attempt to fix the problem. I'm going to revise the question so it's more clear.

Comment: I think I found a problem. You are not returning false from your ajaxregister = function(e) { ... } function. Please try that. It seems redundant with preventDefault, but the docs specifically say "always return false"

Comment: I added it and updated my code in the question. It still doesn't preventDefault after the first submission.

Comment: Without tearing up a reproductable example on my own machine, what I can offer for the time being is: Does the example at http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit work for you repeatedly? If so, I would try dropping their example code on your page. Change it until you find out what is different. I notice the example does not use preventDefault at all.

Comment: If you want to view a live example, you can check it out here: http://www.streetofwalls.com/wsat-firefly/

If you submit the empty registration form you'll see an error message once. Then the second attempt will send you to the wp-login.php page (in IE8).

The preventDefault is there to keep the form from getting submitted BEFORE the ajaxSubmit runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the following lines to the end of the success callback function. Wordpress detects IE and adds the "ie8" id to html tag. You could easily check for ie with jquery or modernizr also.

```
if ( $('html').attr('id') == "ie8" ) {
    $(".widget_reg_widg #registerform").delegate( this, "submit", ajaxregister );
}
```